# Problema para conectarme al servidor reh hat 6.7

Tags: linux, php7, red-hat

Estoy actualizadon el php 5.x a la version 7.x en el red hat 6.7, pero no he podido porque me dice que no se puede conectar al servidor.

Linea de comando:

```
$    wget https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-6.noarch.rpm
$    wget http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm
$    rpm -Uvh remi-release-6.rpm epel-release-latest-6.noarch.rpm
$    rhn-channel --add --channel=rhel-$(uname -i)-server-optional-6
```

Respuesta de la ultima linea de comando:

```
[root@mcssgf user]# rhn-channel --add --channel=rhel-$(uname -i)-server-optional-6
Username: user
Password:
rhn-plugin: Error al comunicarse con el servidor. El mensaje fue:

Error Class Code: 6001
Error Class Info:
     RHN is in the process of being decommissioned and systems are no longer able to receive updates or make use of any RHN services.
     Please see https://access.redhat.com/articles/2979901 for more info.
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que usar RHSM en lugar de RHN. 
Instala `subscription-manager`.